# How do I execute two IBActions at once?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I want to execute two IBActions at once. How do I do this? Eg. moving while zooming.
So it is a smooth effect.

Comment: Did you mean execute two *animations* at once?

Comment: I think the two questions are not related.  In iOS, you can add multiple taget/actions with methods like addTarget on most UIKit objects.  But I don't think that's how you would do smooth animation like moving while zooming.  See CoreAnimation for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question, you don't need to have *two* IBActions for this.
Write only one, and implement the animation code into it. Combined animations will be better served with CoreAnimation as said by Bryanmac.
If you need help about this please tell more about the animations you are waiting for!